# Forcing Secure Browsing

Tags: ssl, https, facebook-apps

Can an App cause Facebook to prompt the user to turn on secure browsing?

If so, how?

I've specified https:// for both the non-secure and secure canvas url, turned off my secure browsing option on my account and it doesn't prompt me to turn it on. It seems to me that I recently visited an app that caused Facebook to display a message indicating that I needed to turn on secure browsing to access the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) through the use of a special response header.

It is supported in Apache, NGINX and Lighttpd.  There is an open source module to add support to IIS. As for browser support for HSTS:

- Internet Explorer:   support expected starting with ie12
- Firefox: 4
- Opera: 12
- Safari: Mavericks (Mac OS X 10.9)
- Chrome: 4.0.211.0

[The OWASP project provides implementation details.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)